# How to write a HashMap to a txt file?

Tags: java, android, file-io, hashmap

I have a HashMap containing some data that I want to write to a file and reload the contents of the file to form the same HashMap.

HashMap is as follows:

```
    HashMap<Long, List<DataPoint>> hashMap = new HashMap<Long, List<DataPoint>>();
```

And DataPoint class is as follows:

```
public class DataPoint {

private int time;
private int songId;

public DataPoint(int songId, int time) {
    this.songId = songId;
    this.time = time;
}

public int getTime() {
    return time;
}

public int getSongId() {
    return songId;
}
 }
```

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds good. What are your having problems with?

Comment: You can convert it to a JSON and simply read/write that JSON to a file. If you use the gson library - it's a real piece of cake!

Comment: Joni: I want to read the file objects as it is to the HashMap.
W.K.S: If the simple one doesn't work, i'm moving to gson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change DataPoint to implement java.io.Serializable and use ObjectOutputStream.writeObject /  ObjectInputStream.readObject. All Java SE collection implementations are Serializable

Comment: -1: Though not explicitly stated in the body, the title specifies a textfile. Default Java serialization will not produce a human-readable output in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Make your data point class as serializable and after use the below code to read and write your map from a text file `    File f = new File("myfile.txt");
    HashMap> hashMap = new HashMap>();

```
List<DataPoint> list = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
list.add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
list.add(new DataPoint(2, 2));
hashMap.put(1L, list);

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
oos.writeObject(hashMap);

oos.flush();
oos.close();

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
HashMap<Long, List<DataPoint>> returnedMap = (HashMap<Long, List<DataPoint>>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
// Use returned object.
System.out.println(returnedMap.get(1L).size());`
```